# GWT - Read file content before uploading

Tags: xml, gwt, file-upload, xml-parsing, fileparsing

I have a requirement where a form needs to be created where users can upload multiple file at once. Additional requirements are:

1. Perform click side validation before uploading. If one of more files are of type other than **.XML** or **.ZIP** then do not send the request to the server, throw an alert msg to the user.
2. Read the XML files (Full parsing of XML using DOM) one by one (Before uploading) to validate them all. Keep parsing and validating the XML files and tell the user that '***Buddy, ABC.xml file that you are trying to upload has a tag  which is not correct!***'

All these has to be done at the client side using GWT. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Both of your requirements can be implemented.

In general, if it can be done with JavaScript, it can be done with GWT.

Comment: May I get some example program please?

Comment: StackOverflow is for specific programming questions. When you write this code and run into a bug or a specific issue, we will be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

The browser FileReader api could be used to read the files. So you could use GWT Elemental wrapper for the FileReader api.

http://docs.sencha.com/gxt/4.x/javadoc/gwt-2.8.0/gwt-elemental-2.8.0/index.html?elemental/html/FileReader.html - FileReader Javadoc